# How to get an element by index in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have a form with some elements in it. What I want to do is check if there is a specific element in position x. Is there a way so I can get the element x by its index value?

Comment: You should clarify, perhaps with an example. If I understand well, you want to get a reference to for instance the 3rd textfield in a form. Is this correct ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the third textfield, you can use [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

```
var thirdTextField = formcomponent.query('textfield')[2];
```

or using `down`

```
var thirdTextField = formcomponent.down('textfield:nth-child(3)'):
```

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i2k

```
    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 350,
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaults: {anchor: '100%'},

        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Middle Name',
            name: 'middle',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'last',
            allowBlank: false
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    form.down('textfield:nth-child(3)').setValue('Johnson')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//0-based index
var element = form.items.getAt(index);
```